# Will LMAX Disruptor work on Android?

Tags: android, disruptor-pattern, lmax

Anyone had any experience with running LMAX Disruptor on Android? Will it work and are there any compatibility issues?

Answer (score 2):

I haven't used it yet, but plan to. I don't think it will work out of the box. LMAX uses sun.misc.Unsafe to do some low-level programming which is not completely supported in Android.

Comment: Is there an alternative?